# Django Multiple Form as dynamic checkboxes

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

Hoping there is a quick slick Django-esque solution to the following challenge that doesn't involve `JavaScript`.

Currently, I have a form created that shows a Many to Many field as a simple multiple (the built in behaviour in Django) utalising the following:

**Forms.py:**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ['email_address']
```

**Template:**

```
<form  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}            
    <button class="btn" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    email_address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, null=True)
```

However, to ease the experience for the user (and improve mobile performance) I would like to instead show a list with checkboxes next to each.

Is there an easy way to achieve this without either JavaScript or manually setting each option in the forms.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much easier way would be to provide the widget for **subscriptions** in `Meta` class of `ProfileForm`

```
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    exclude = ['email_address']
    widgets = {
        'subscriptions': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    }
```